# Failure to Execute UPDATE Query in ASP.net using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I have been searching in several forums including this one about the trouble I am currently facing.

Currently I am developing a website using Visual Studio 2017 and the database runs with MS Access 2007. The problem I am facing is perhaps not an error, because it does not show any error messages, although I have put Try and Catch on my codes.

So I am trying to execute an UPDATE query for a table I have in Access but it fails to update. The purpose is to update a table called 'DataDiriKaryawan'.

Prior to updating, I SELECT the data per 'nip' (ID as primary key) and display it on my web form by calling Function 'isi' on page_load. Then users are able to edit the data based on preexisting data.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session("editval") = "WAMB17001"
    isi()
End Sub

  Protected Sub isi()
    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim nip As String = Session("editval")

    Try
        Using command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM DataDiriKaryawan WHERE NIP='" & nip & "'", mdl_koneksi.connection)
            dr = command.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()

            lblnip.Text = dr.GetValue(0)
            txtnamadepan.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
            txtnamabelakang.Text = dr.GetValue(2)
            txtnoktp.Text = dr.GetValue(3)
            txtnonpwp.Text = dr.GetValue(4)
            txtalamatktp.Text = dr.GetValue(5)
            txtkabktp.Text = dr.GetValue(6)
            txtprovinsiktp.Text = dr.GetValue(7)
            txtkodeposktp.Text = dr.GetValue(8)
            txtnegaraktp.Text = dr.GetValue(9)

            txtalamattgl.Text = dr.GetValue(10)
            txtkabtgl.Text = dr.GetValue(11)
            txtprovtgl.Text = dr.GetValue(12)
            txtkodepostgl.Text = dr.GetValue(13)
            txtnegaratgl.Text = dr.GetValue(14)

            txtkontak1.Text = dr.GetValue(15)
            txtkontak2.Text = dr.GetValue(16)
            txtkontakdarurat.Text = dr.GetValue(17)
            txthbgn.Text = dr.GetValue(18)

            If dr.GetValue(19) = "Laki-laki" Then
                rblaki.Checked = True
            Else
                rbperempuan.Checked = False
            End If

            txtnikah.Text = dr.GetValue(20)
            txtjmlhanak.Text = dr.GetValue(21)
            txttmptlahir.Text = dr.GetValue(22)
            txttgllahir.Text = dr.GetValue(23)
            txtpendidikan.Text = dr.GetValue(24)
            txtnorek.Text = dr.GetValue(25)

            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            dr.Close()

        End Using
    Catch

    End Try
```

Upon editing of data in web form then the UPDATE query is executed.

```
Private Sub simpan()
    Dim nip As String = Session("editval")

    Try
        Using command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE DataDiriKaryawan SET nama_depan=@nama_depan, nama_akhir=@nama_akhir, ktp_no=@ktp_no, no_npwp=@no_npwp, alamat_ktp=@alamat_ktp, 
        kota_ktp=@kota_ktp, provinsi_ktp=@provinsi_ktp, kodepos_ktp=@kodepos_ktp, negara_ktp=@negara_ktp, alamat_tgl=@alamat_ktp, kota_tgl=@kota_tgl, provinsi_tgl=@provinsi_tgl,
        kodepos_tgl=@kodepos_tgl, negara_tgl=@negara_tgl, cp1=@cp1, cp2=@cp2, kontak_darurat=@kontak_darurat, hbgn_kontak=@hbgn_kontak, jenis_kelamin=@jenis_kelamin, status_nikah=@status_nikah,
        jmlh_anak=@jmlh_anak, tempat_lahir=@tempat_lahir, tgl_lahir=@tgl_lahir, pendidikan_terakhir=@pendidikan_terakhir, rek_niaga=@rek_niaga WHERE NIP='" & nip & "'", mdl_koneksi.connection)
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@nama_depan", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnamadepan.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@nama_akhir", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnamabelakang.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ktp_no", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnoktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@no_npwp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnonpwp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@no_npwp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnonpwp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@alamat_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtalamatktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kota_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkabktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kota_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkabktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@provinsi_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtprovinsiktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kodepos_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkodeposktp.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@negara_ktp", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnegaraktp.Text

            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@alamat_tgl", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtalamattgl.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kota_tgl", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkabtgl.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@provinsi_tgl", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtprovtgl.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kodepos_tgl", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkodepostgl.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@negara_tgl", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnegaratgl.Text

            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@cp1", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkontak1.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@cp2", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkontak2.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@kontak_darurat", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtkontakdarurat.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@hbgn_kontak", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txthbgn.Text

            If rblaki.Checked = True Then
                command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@jenis_kelamin", OleDbType.Char)).Value = rblaki.Text
            Else
                command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@jenis_kelamin", OleDbType.Char)).Value = rbperempuan.Text
            End If

            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@status_nikah", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnikah.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@jmlh_anak", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtjmlhanak.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@tempat_lahir", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txttmptlahir.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@tgl_lahir", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txttgllahir.Text

            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@pendidikan_terakhir", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtpendidikan.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@rek_niaga", OleDbType.Char)).Value = txtnorek.Text
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@NIP", OleDbType.Char)).Value = lblnip.Text


            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            Session("editval") = ""
            Page.Response.Redirect("FrmRedirectInsertData.aspx")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblpesan.Visible = True
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Then Function 'simpan', containing the UPDATE query is called in btnsimpan.click.

```
Protected Sub btnsimpan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsimpan.Click
    simpan()
    Session("editval") = ""
End Sub
```

Now here are the anomalies:

1. Despite having try catch, I am not shown any error messages. The web form just refreshed to the same data as previous and the table in MS Access is not updated.
2. If I did not call Function 'isi' on page_load to fill the web form with preexisting data, the UPDATE query works very find.
3. I have used the same methods and codes in other forms for different tables and it worked just fine.

I have been spending a couple of days now, trying to compare the tables in Access and codes in Visual Studio and I have found no difference of codes and settings/properties.

Thus, I may need your kind assistance to solve this problems. Cheers!

Comment: did you open your `connection`?  you just have a `connection.close()` but you don't have `connection.open()`

Comment: Place a breakpoint on that `ExecuteNonQuery` call to make sure it's hit.  Also, check what value it returns. If's not greater than zero then it means that the call is succeeding but it's not finding any matching records to modify.

Comment: Woah! I just realised that you are running a web application and you have `MsgBox` calls in your `Catch` blocks. What's up with that? `MsgBox` is for Windows Forms applications. You need to actually debug your code and make sure that the code you think is executing actually is. Use breakpoints and step through your code.  Also, don't call `MsgBox` in web applications.

Comment: @kiLLua I tried putting it before the UPDATE query and it still failed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no, that msgbox is only for development purposes. Not to be published. Hahaha.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the result just came out. The Hit Count = break always (currently 1)

Comment: So it seems that your `UPDATE` statement is being executed. Now, what value does `ExecuteNonQuery` return?

Comment: @jmcilhinney here is the value="error BC30451: 'ExecuteNonQuery' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

So it seems.

Comment: Well no, that's not a value. That's an error message. I didn't look closely at your variable names but it seems that you have encountered a name clash due to using a ridiculous variable name.  You have an `OleDbConnection` variable named `connection`, an `OleDbDataReader` variable named `dr` and an `OleDbCommand` variable named `OleDb`. Do you not see an issue there, even if it did work? Inconsistency is ALWAYS a bad thing unless done for a very specific reason that actually helps. Name that variable `command` as it should be and this issue goes away.

Comment: @jmcilhinney have changed it to 'command' still doesn't work. I have been searching error BC30451 for a while and in some discussion it is associated with name clashing between forms. 

I did copy paste the design of this web form from a previous form with similar fields. Currently I am making a new form with fresh design naming. I'll see how it goes and keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Made a new web form from scratch and it still doesn't work. I have changed the variable to command as you said.

Comment: Do you still get the same error message as before? If not, what does happen? If `ExecuteNonQuery` executes successfully, what value does it return?

Comment: @jmcilhinney still the same error message as before.

Comment: Can you edit your question and update the code? I can't see a reason for that error if you've done as I thought you should.

Comment: @jmcilhinney done.

Comment: I'm at a loss to see how that error could occur with that code. I can only assume that something is corrupt somewhere.

Comment: @jmcilhinney but as I said, the 'update' command works well without the 'select' function.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think you might be correct about something corrupted. I put a breakpoint in all of the ExecuteNonQuery in all my forms and it returned the same error. But it seems to work just fine for the other forms. Hardly any fuzz. Could this be a bug in VS2017?

Comment: Are saying that `ExecuteNonQuery` works fine in other projects but nowhere in this project? It may well be a bug in VS that caused something in your project to be corrupted. What that bug may be and what that corruption may be is anyone's guess.

Comment: @jmcilhinney No. I currently have 5 web forms using ExecuteNonQuery. 4 works fine but if I put break point it still returns the same error as mentioned before. But the query is successfully executed. This one form we've been talking about doesn't execute the query. I haven't developed any projects using VS2017 before. I used VS2010 before and never encountered something like this.

Comment: That does sound bizarre. I've been using VS 2017 since it was first released and it has had its share of issues but not necessarily excessive. I don't use Web Forms myself but I've not heard of similar behaviour from anyone else. I'd suggest creating a new test project and seeing whether it behaves the same way. That should tell you whether it's a project-specific issue.